Making Vertex Shader face Camera like billboard in THREE.JS
Im attempting to make a vertex shader that i can apply to a mesh to make all its quads turn into billboards. I found this code is the closest i could get it however it does not fully face the camera when applying the positions again: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/bold-golick-w2w6jc
  // Pass UV coordinates to fragment shader
  v_uvs = uv;

  // Calculate initial offset from UVs
  vec3 vertexOffset = calcInitialOffsetFromUVs(0.0);

  // Extract camera right and up vectors from the view matrix (columns of the view matrix)
  vec3 cameraRight = normalize(vec3(viewMatrix[0][0], viewMatrix[1][0], viewMatrix[2][0]));
  vec3 cameraUp = normalize(vec3(viewMatrix[0][1], viewMatrix[1][1], viewMatrix[2][1]));

  // Calculate the offset in view space
  vec3 offset = (vertexOffset.x) * cameraRight + (vertexOffset.y) * cameraUp;
  offset.x += 0.0;
  offset.y += 3.0;
  offset.z += 0.0;
  // WHEN APPLYING THE POSITION HERE IT GETS SKEWED  

  // Add the offset to the view position
  vec4 billboardPosition = vec4(offset, 1.0);

  // Transform the final position to clip space
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * billboardPosition;

The billboard only faces the camera correctly if i simply set the offset without reapplying the position variable to position them all correctly again. As soon as i do that they get skewed.
I have see the answer in this question:
THREE.js - Billboard Vertex Shader
However it only applies to the entire object and isnt isolated to the individual quads.
